# CSS Background image, fade once loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I want to fade-in the "image" once it is loaded from an external url, but show a "imgPlaceholder" right from the beginning from local resources.

The HTML looks like this:

```
  <div className="bg-img" style={imgDivStyle}></div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
const imgDivStyle = {
  background: `url('${image}'), url('${imgPlaceholder}')`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
};
```

What I want to happen: Show "imgPlaceholder" from beginning and Fade-in "image" once it is loaded.

What is actually happening: "imgPlaceholder" is shown from beginning "image" is showing up instantly once it is loaded.

Is this achievable by pure CSS? Or do I need to load in the image using e.g. jQuery and trigger an animation manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check if the image has loaded with css alone so you could do something like the following (comments in code to show what is happening):

```js
$('.inner').each(function() {
  var div = $(this),
    background = div.data('background');  // get background

  $('<img/>').attr('src', background).load(function() {  // create an image element with inner background and load it
    $(this).remove();  // remove it
    
    // set the inner background image and fade in:
    div.css('background-image', 'url(' + background + ')').delay(200).fadeIn(2000); // need a little delay to let the div render it's bg image before the fade starts
  });
});
```

```css
.default,
.inner {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  
  /* just make sure inner div is same size as outer */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.default {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/900/900/city/1/); /* default background */
}

.inner {
  display:none; /* start of hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default"><!-- default div with default background image -->
  <div class="inner" data-background="https://lorempixel.com/900/900/city/2/"><!-- inner div with background-image set as data attribute -->

  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to create the inner div on the fly, you can do something like this:

```js
$('.background').each(function() {
  var div = $(this),
    background = div.data('background'), // get background
    html = div.html();  // get any contents

  $('<img/>').attr('src', background).load(function() {  // create an image element with inner background and load it
    $(this).remove();  // remove it
    div.empty();       // empty current div
    
    // create an inner div:
    $('<div/>')
      .css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + background + ')',
        'display': 'none'
      })                  // add background and hide
      .addClass('inner')      
      .html(html)           
      .appendTo(div)      // append to default div
      .delay(175)
      .fadeIn(2000); // need a little delay to let the div render it's bg image before the fade starts
  });
});
```

```css
.background,
.inner {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.background {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/900/900/city/1/); /* default background */
  
  /* just make sure inner div is same size as outer */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.inner {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background" data-background="https://lorempixel.com/900/900/city/2/"><!-- default div with default background image,  new background image set as data attribute -->
</div>
```

Comment: alright, thanks for the detailed answer. Works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I found a reference that utilizes @keyframes along with some attributes like 'opacity' within an animation frame.

You can try referencing some of the code in the link here -

https://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk

```
@keyframes fade
{
0%   {opacity:1}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: hmm... with a solution like this I'd have to have 2 div's and then still need to check via script whether the "image" is loaded to start the animation. What I'm looking for is a solution that might work with the double "url" setup. But this might be a valid work-around. thanks!